# How do I pass information / data to a query?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

It's my first time using React and GraphQl. I stored the data I wanted to send to my graphQl database using useStates but now I'm unsure on how I can actually send said data to my database. I don't know much about query's, but I know they don't work like functions do, so I can't send data using the parenthesis operator. I read up a bit and saw some stuff related to passing objects and query strings. Could anyone help figure out the right way to do this?

I looked around the web and stack overflow for previously answered questions and articles. I'm looking for some information on how to manipulate query's

**Update #1**: I figured out that in order to send data to my DynamoDB database I need two things, first I need to encapsulate my data into a JSON object like this

```
const entry ={
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        email: email,
        address:address
      }
```

then using the API and graphOperation library's from aws I can insert the objects into the queries I want to use from graphQl to add items to my data base.

```js
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';

let response = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createPerson,{input: entry}));
```

however I now have a new problem: every time I call the this function

```js
async function addPerson() {
    console.log(name);
    console.log(phone);
    console.log(email);
    console.log(address);
    // JSON containing the data i want to send to my createPerson query
    try{
      const entry ={
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        email: email,
        address:address
      }
      let response = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createPerson,{input: entry}));
      console.log(response.data)
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
}
```

I get this error and I have no idea why.

```
Error: No credentials
    at GraphQLAPIClass.<anonymous> (GraphQLAPI.ts:144:1)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:100:1)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81:1)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:71:1)
```

I tried rebuilding my database on amplify, and looking at posts on stack overflow

Comment: You need to provide some code as well to show what you have already done